# Extending paired t-test to compare agreement between three or more analytical instruments over time

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, paired-data, agreement-statistics

I have three instruments that measure the concentration of dust in the air, and I want to test whether the mean difference between their measurements is zero (i.e that they give the same measurement).  The instruments produce one measurement per period of time (no repeats), and the concentration of dust naturally varies over time. In a situation with only two instruments (x & y), I would calculate the difference, d , between the measurements at each time point
d<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>1</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>,..., d<sub>k</sub> = x<sub>k</sub>-y<sub>k</sub>
to perform a one-sample *t*-test on the mean difference between each instrument (i.e paired *t*-test).  The mean of the differences is more useful than the difference of the means because the concentrations are so variable over time.
For >2 instruments, I could repeat the pairwise analysis but that would increase likelihood of Type 1 error.
I am looking at a Repeated Measures ANOVA for this situation but can't figure out how to set it up so as to be comparing the difference in measurements at each time point, as opposed to the instrument means across the entire period in which I expect there to naturally be a lot of variation.

Example data with instruments x,y,z:

| Hour | Measure x | Measure y | Measure z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 30 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 35 |
| 3 | 10 | 11 | 51 |

Instrument z clearly doesn't agree with x&y

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "similar"?  What precisely would your null hypothesis be?

Comment: What about including time as a random effect? Or, if there are many time points, model a common trend in time using a spline? Also condider including the tag [tag:agreement-statistics]

Comment: @whuber I edited my post to try to be more specific. Thanks!